# Mi modulo de busqueda no trae datos

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, busqueda

Hola es mi primera pregunta en este foro voy a intentar ser breve.
Hice un formulario de busqueda para un sistema escolar en el que estoy trabajando, cree el form, y el codigo en php, pero cuando intento traer los datos no me regresa nada, revise la query y funciona.

```
<body>
```

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="panel box-table">
    
        <div class="box-plan">
        <div style="text-align:left;">
            <input type="button" onclick="history.back()" value="Volver" class="button">
            <h2 class="box-tittle">Buscar personas en el sistema</h2>
        </div>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
            
            <form action=""  method="POST" class="panel" class="form_search">
            
                <input type="text" size="40" name="busqueda" id="busqueda" placeholder="Ingresar Documento, Nombre o Apellido"></td>
                <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Buscar" class="button" style="padding: 10px 10px;">
                
            </form>
            
            <?php
            require_once('config.php');
            if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
                $busqueda = strtoupper($_POST['busqueda']);
                $registros = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM persona WHERE persona_AyN LIKE '%busqueda%' OR persona_doc LIKE '%busqueda%'");
                echo '<table class="panel box-table" border="1" style="margin: 0 auto;">';
                echo '<tr><th>Nombre y Apellido</th> <th>Documento</th></tr>';
                while ($reg = $registros->fetch_array()) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>';
                    echo $reg['persona_doc'];
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '<td>';
                    echo $reg['persona_AyN'];      
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '<td>';
                    echo '<a href="planilla_intermedia_alta.php?persona_id='.$reg['persona_id'].'">Registrar Alta</a>';
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
                echo '<table>';
            }
            ?>
                    
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
</div>
```

La base de datos es una base sencilla de prueba con la tabla personas, id,nya,doc y fechanac
Si me pueden ayudar seria genial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que le estás mandando un string a la consulta SQL y no la variable capturada del POST:

```
... persona_AyN LIKE '%busqueda%' OR persona_doc LIKE '%busqueda%' ...
```

Debe ser:

```
... persona_AyN LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR persona_doc LIKE '%$busqueda%' ...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me siento tonto